# Token Encryption on id token

Tags: openiddict

Does OpenIddict token encryption for the id token only encrypt things on the server side and should it be returning the id token to the browser as json?

Based on the OpenIddict documentation I have set up my production environment to use assymetric encryption using X509 certificates for my id token.

According to the docs here: [Registering a certificate](https://documentation.openiddict.com/configuration/encryption-and-signing-credentials.html#registering-a-certificate-recommended-for-production-ready-scenarios), it is recommended to use a separate X509 encryption and signing certificate for the tokens in a production environment.

When configuring OpenIddict in Startup.cs you would then use these certificates as follows:

`options.AddEncryptionCertificate([Thumbprint of certificate goes here]);                         options.AddSigningCertificate([Thumbprint of certificate goes here);`

My question is:  Is the encryption only handled server side?  When examining the traffic with Fiddler, I can see that my id token is returned in readable json. I am wondering why it is not returned in an encrypted format.

Comment: did you figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

I think the token value you're seeing has been encrypted, so if you were to dump it in a JWT decoder like https://jwt.io/ then you won't be able to see the real values or claims.

It then gets decrypted server side so the claims and information in the token can be used

...at least that's the way I understand it!